# SQL One to Many JOIN Without Subquery?

Tags: sql, join, limit, one-to-many

I've got a question related to a 1 to n query which I was hoping someone could shed some light on.

Here's what I'm looking to accomplish.

I have several homes each home may have multiple occupants. I'd like to select 5 homes and all the associated occupants. I know of two ways of doing. The most common of these is a select statement to get the 5 homes and then a second select statement using IN condition to get associated occupants. The other way to do this is a variation of the two queries using one query with a subquery.

Is there any other way to accomplish without the use of a subquery?

**Update:**

Seems the consensus is this is not possible with the use of a subquery.

Comment: FYI, the OPs two methods are the least efficient ways to get the data.

Comment: @gbn I'm using MySQL but was hoping for a SQL compliant implementation.

Answer (score 5):

You'd normally use a JOIN to get related data from both tables

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Homes ORDER BY something) H
   JOIN
   Occupants O ON H.HomeID = O.HomeID
```

However, the TOP 5 needs to be applied to Homes only. It'd be LIMIT with MySQL, not TOP too.

Edit:

A window/ranking function still needs a sub-query or some indirection such as a CTE to allow filtering on the generated number.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something) AS RowNum
    FROM Homes) H
   JOIN
   Occupants O ON H.HomeID = O.HomeID
WHERE
   RowNum <= 5

;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT
    *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something) AS RowNum
   FROM
    Homes
 )
SELECT
   *
FROM
   CTE H
   JOIN
   Occupants O ON H.HomeID = O.HomeID
WHERE
   RowNum <= 5
```

Comment: typo - Occupents O ON H.HomeID = O.HomeID

Comment: +1, a join is the way to go, with a derived table to get the TOP 5

Comment: +1 I can't think of a better way than this, either. @Andre, is there a reason you *must* not use a subquery? Maybe we can attack this from a different angle.

Comment: @Hogan RANK() would work if *it were used in the subquery* in place of TOP - see comments on your answer below.

Comment: @djacobson it's a matter of curiosity, I wanted to see if it could be done. From what I'm seeing it doesn't seem to be.

If it matters I'm using MySQL, but would like a solution that's ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, depending on DB engine support:

```
select *
from
   (
       select top 5
           home_id,
           ... -- other columns
       from 
           home
       order by
           awesomeness desc
   ) h
       inner join occupant o on o.home_id = h.home_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner join.  Each home will be listed multiple times, once for each occupant in that home.

```
select Home.HomeName, Occupant.OccupantName from Home 
inner join Occupant on Home.Id=Occupant.HomeId
```

And then you'll get:

```
Home1 OccupantA
Home1 OccupantB
Home2 OccupantC
Home2 OccupantD
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server (2005 and higher) you could use a CTE

```
WITH MyTopFive (MyId, MyOtherField, SomeField) AS
(
SELECT TOP 5 MyId, MyOtherField, SomeField FROM Homes ORDER BY SomeField
)

SELECT * 
FROM Mytopfive t5
JOIN Occupants o ON o.myid = t5.myid
```

gbn has the best generic database solution though.

Comment: Is a CTE appreciably different from a sub-query, in terms of what the query processor is doing? That's not a rhetorical question, I'm not actually sure. :)

Comment: A CTE and a derived table are essentially the same. A derived table is not the same as a correlated subquery which runs row-by-row and should be avoided. Neither a derived table nor a CTE should be hard on performance if written well.

Answer (score -1):

*sql server specific*

yes you could use a join to do this.  you did not show your db schema but if I take a guess you probably want something like this:

```
 select *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY home.homeid ORDER BY home.homeid DESC) as houserank
 from home
 join occupant on home.homeid = occupant.homeid
 where  houserank < 6
```

Comment: I assume the problem is, that query returns the top five results in the resultset "all occupants of all homes", not the the resultset "all occupants of the top 5 homes"...

Comment: if only it did what OP asked. Top 5 homes. Not top 5 rows of JOINed tables.

Comment: @djacobson : not what the original post says... he says 5 homes with all occupants.

Comment: @Hogan Yes. And your query doesn't return "5 homes with all occupants". It returns five records from the joined sets of homes and occupants. Depending on the ordering, that could be five occupants of the same home.

Comment: On SQL Server: Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.  Other databases may allow for this.

Comment: @Hogan What @KM said. Windowed functions occurred to me, too, but unfortunately they *still* require a subquery! Chalk this up to being tougher than it looks. :)

Comment: @djacobson : they require a sub-query or they are (in effect) a subquery?

Comment: @Hogan Because they can only appear in the SELECT list, they require a subquery. As @KM points out, I only know that for sure on SQL Server.